# Why triggering `catch` in `fetch` depends on how I return a response in first `then`?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch, fetch

Consider this code:

```
fetch('https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/json')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(() => {
    console.log('SUCCESS');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('FAIL');
  })
```

It's intentionally a wrong route and it returns an error with code 404. But nevertheless, the `SUCCESS` case is triggering.

However, if I replace `res => res.text()` with `res => res.json()` it catch `FAIL` as it supposed to be.

Moreover, placing absolutely wrong URL (I mean non-existing server) leads to correct cathing `FAIL` even with `res.text()`.

I find this behavior a bit strange and tricky and would be grateful for some clarification.

P. S. I know, that here may help this precaution: `if (!res.ok) throw new Error();`, just curious why it's going this way.

Comment: There is no network problem and *the server returns a code*. That's successful as far as "fetch results in a response" is concerned. (`res.json` only throws because your response body is not valid JSON, it could quite well be even with 404)

Comment: 4xx response !== failure.

Comment: @Bergi huh, perhaps you're right) Didn't think about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It's intentionally a wrong route and it returns an error with code 404. But nevertheless, the SUCCESS case is triggering.

This is by design. The `fetch` call only promises to make the request and return a response - any response. It will reject only in case of network problems, such as your non-existing server when you changed the domain.

The status code or body content do not matter in determining whether it's valid HTTP response. To check whether it's HTTP status is successful, you have to test `res.ok` as you already stated.

> However, if I replace `res => res.text()` with `res => res.json()` it catch FAIL as it supposed to be.

Yes, but that's not because the request failed. It throws because your response body is not valid JSON - which it could quite well have be even with 404.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer** is your Promise is throwing an error on `res.json()`

**Long answer (explanation)**

Your initial http call succeeds and hence executes the 'success' promise

- This is because the url exists and responds with successful status code and returns an html page represented by string/text
- the response it returns is just a textual representation of a **page** that happens to display the text 'page not found', but **your** call status to get this **page** is NOT 404, it is in fact a 200, or you wouldn't be able to see the page...... (quite a mind bender)

**BUT...** even though your call is actually successful, when an unhandled error is thrown anywhere in the Promise you will ALWAYS trigger the 'fail' promise (the *catch*), that is just how a promise works.

**Now....** Basically that uri returns a textual representation of an html page, so calling `res.text()` is successful, BUT when you call `res.json()` on 'text' data it throws an error because the response is not json, and that error bubbles up and eventually is caught by the catch of the promise. If you want json you must first know the data type you expect from your response and then convert to what you want.

**Lesson Here is** know your return type so you know what to expect and code for, it just doesn't make sense to call a uri and not know what type of data it returns.